# AFNetworking upload image, response is successful, but file not found on server

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I use AFNetworking to upload image to server.The http response says image upload successfully. But the file can't be found on server. It seems that the server can't save the image I uploaded. The image is from UIImagePicker. Here is my code

```
    + (void)httpUploadJPGImageWithParam:(NSDictionary *)param path:(NSString *)path image:(UIImage*)image success:(SucceedBlock)successBlock failed:(Fail)failedBlock
{


    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:path parameters:param constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"image"];
        //[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        successBlock(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (failedBlock) {
            failedBlock([error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }];


}
```

Comment: What happens on the server side?

Comment: It' of course server problem. May be your server hasn't given permission to store file in your folder where you want to store the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the server code, but usually you'd use

```
- (void)appendPartWithFileData:(NSData *)data
                          name:(NSString *)name
                      fileName:(NSString *)fileName
                      mimeType:(NSString *)mimeType;
```

Usually when using multipart requests to upload file (e.g. to be parsed by `$_FILES` in PHP), it's expecting a file name and mime type, too.